# Filepath Checker

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to check if particular files exist in folders.

For example in my code, there are 3 files that belong to folder 1, and 1 file that belongs to folder 2.

I want the output to let me know if the file "exists" or "does not exist"

There is an error. `filename3 = ActiveSheet.Range("B21").Value`  does not exist, but the Message Box displays that it does. I'm thinking its to do with the way I joined the filepath + filename.

Also, is there any way to make the code more elegant?

```vb
Sub InputChecker()
    Dim filepath As String
    Dim filename As String
    Dim result1 As String
    Dim fullpath As String
    
    filepath1 = ActiveSheet.Range("H14").Value
    filename1 = ActiveSheet.Range("H15").Value
    filename2 = ActiveSheet.Range("H16").Value
    filename3 = ActiveSheet.Range("B21").Value

    filepath2 = ActiveSheet.Range("H18").Value
    filename4 = ActiveSheet.Range("H19").Value

    Dim fullpath1 As String
    fullpath1 = filepath1 & filename1
    If Dir(fullpath1) = VBA.Constants.vbNullString Then
        result1 = filename1 + ", File does not exist"
    Else
        result1 = filename1 + ", File exist"
    End If

    Dim fullpath2 As String
    fullpath2 = filepath1 & filename2
    If fullpath2 = VBA.Constants.vbNullString Then
        result2 = filename2 + ", File does not exist"
    Else
        result2 = filename2 + ", File exist"
    End If

    Dim fullpath3 As String
    fullpath3 = filepath1 & filename3
    If fullpath3 = VBA.Constants.vbNullString Then
        result3 = filename3 + ", File does not exist"
    Else
        result3 = filename3 + ", File exist"
    End If

    Dim fullpath4 As String
    fullpath4 = filepath2 & filename4
    If fullpath4 = VBA.Constants.vbNullString Then
        result4 = filename4 + ", File does not exist"
    Else
        result4 = filename4 + ", File exist"
    End If

    MsgBox (result1 & vbNewLine & result2 & vbNewLine & result3 & vbNewLine & result4)
    Cells(18, 3).Value = Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")

End Sub
```

Comment: You've got `If Dir(Fullpath1)` which is correct, you need the `Dir` command on the other tests for fullpath 2, 3 and 4

Comment: Oh wow I totally missed that simple part, thanks for point it out. It is working properly now. Just looks like very clunky coding now.

Answer (score 0):

Having answered the functionality question, cleaning up the code is easy - you just need some arrays and loops rather than all those separate variables.

```
Sub InputChecker()
    Dim Sht As Worksheet: Set Sht = ActiveSheet
    'String arrays for files, folders and fullpaths:
    Dim strFile(1 To 4, 1 To 2) As String, strPath(1 To 2) As String, result As String 'we only need the one result string
    
    With Sht
        strPath(1) = .Range("H14").Value
        strPath(2) = .Range("H18").Value
        
        'use strFile(x, 1) for file names
        strFile(1, 1) = .Range("H15").Value
        strFile(2, 1) = .Range("H16").Value
        strFile(3, 1) = .Range("B21").Value
        strFile(4, 1) = .Range("H19").Value
        
        'use strFile(x, 2) for fullpaths
        For a = 1 To 4
            strFile(a, 2) = strPath(IIf(a < 4, 1, 2)) & strFile(a, 1)
        Next
        
        'Now loop through to build the result string
        For a = 1 To 4
            'file name gets added first each time
            result = result & strFile(a, 1) & "; "
            If Len(Dir(strFile(a, 2))) = 0 Then
                result = result & "File does not exist" & vbNewLine
            Else
                result = result & "File exists" & vbNewLine
            End If
        Next
        
        'That leaves a spare line break at the end of result string, remove it;
        If Right(result, 1) = vbNewLine Then result = Left(result, Len(result) - 1)

        'Message box (I added button formatting and a title)
        MsgBox prompt:=result, Buttons:=vbOKOnly + vbInformation, Title:="Result"

        .Cells(18, 3).Value = Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")

    End With 'sht

End Sub
```